# React Native iOS application not working after migrating tipsi-stripe to @stripe/stripe-react-native, I need help to run app again

Tags: ios, react-native

React Native iOS application not working after migrating tipsi-stripe to @stripe/stripe-react-native,It is showing some errors when I am making build of an app after uninstalled tipis-stripe and installed @stripe/stripe-react-native, please let me know solution of this.

------- Code (App.js) -------
/*

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
 
 import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
 
 import {
   SafeAreaView,
   ScrollView,
   StatusBar,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   useColorScheme,
   View,
 } from 'react-native';

 import PaymentScreen from './PaymentScreen';

 
 export default class CheckoutSignin extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
       <StripeProvider
      publishableKey="pk_test_qblFNYngBkEdjEZ16jxxoWSM"
      urlScheme="your-url-scheme" // required for 3D Secure and bank redirects
      merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.{{YOUR_APP_NAME}}" // required for Apple Pay
    >
    <PaymentScreen/>
     </StripeProvider>
   );
 };
 
}
```

*/

------- (Package.json) -------
"dependencies": {

```
"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.22.1"
```

},

[image: Error : screenshot-1]

[image: Error : screenshot-2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer. I had SWIFT_VERSION pinned to 5.0, but iOS 13 came with Swift 5.2 so pinning Swift to 5.2 (and removing the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH pointing to 5.0) solved it.

That means, this:

```
  LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
            "\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
            "\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
            "\"$(inherited)\"",
        );
        SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
```

should look like this:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
                "\"$(inherited)\"",
            );
            SWIFT_VERSION = 5.2;
```